# TextBox1.TextChanged event shows MsgBox twice

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I have a problem with the TextBox1.TextChanged event. 
My code :

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    MsgBox("txt was changed")
    TextBox1.Clear()
End Sub
```

The problem is that the MsgBox is shown twice, but I want to show it just one time and clear the TextBox. How can i do that?

Comment: Clear triggers again a call to your event handler

Comment: yes i know that but i want to clean the textbox and show the msgbox just one time , can i do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ways:

Temporarily remove the handler to prevent the event firing again:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    MsgBox("txt was changed")
    RemoveHandler TextBox1.TextChanged, AddressOf TextBox1_TextChanged
    TextBox1.Clear()
    AddHandler TextBox1.TextChanged, AddressOf TextBox1_TextChanged
End Sub
```

or

Create a field to check if the event is originating from itself:

```
Dim textBoxAlreadyChanging As boolean = False

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    If Not textBoxAlreadyChanging Then
        MsgBox("txt was changed")
        textBoxAlreadyChanging = True
        TextBox1.Clear()
        textBoxAlreadyChanging = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Out of interest, which one did you use?

Comment: the 1st method is perfect then the 2nd , thanks egain :D